# Unable to connect to Mongo DB with Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb

I have created a Cosmos DB database in Azure and using Mongo API. I have created the client and configured like this-

```
_mongoDbConnectionString = configuration["MongoDBConnectionString"];
_databaseName = configuration["MongoDBName"];
_client = new MongoClient(_mongoDbConnectionString);
_database = _client.GetDatabase(_databaseName);
_collectionName = configuration["MongoDBCollectionName"];
```

Then trying to write data-

```
_database.GetCollection<dynamic>(_collectionName).InsertOne(data);
```

It fails with error-

> A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using
>   CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors =
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector,
>   LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000
>   } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode
>   : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers :
>   [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint :
>   "Unspecified/botframeworkcosmos.documents.azure.com:10255" }",
>   EndPoint: "Unspecified/botframeworkcosmos.documents.azure.com:10255",
>   State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException:
>   "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while
>   opening a connection to the server. --->
>   System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException: A
>   connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to respond

I tried this solution- [A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314245/a-timeout-occured-after-30000ms-selecting-a-server-using-compositeserverselector) but it did not work.

I also tried setting the SSL policies like this to configure the client-

```
_mongoDbConnectionString = configuration["MongoDBConnectionString"];
_databaseName = configuration["MongoDBName"];
MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(
  new MongoUrl(_mongoDbConnectionString)
);
settings.SslSettings =
  new SslSettings() { EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 };
_client = new MongoClient(settings);
_database = _client.GetDatabase(_databaseName);
_collectionName = configuration["MongoDBCollectionName"];
```

I still get the same error. What is weird is, the same code, it was all working yesterday.

**Update**
I deleted the database and created a new one. Still same problem.

Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: You sure your connection string/url is correct in the appsettings.json? The endpoint entry looks a bit odd with that `Unspecified/` in front of `Unspecified/botframeworkcosmos.documents.azure.com:10255`

Comment: @Tseng My connection string is like this- `mongodb://chatbotcosmos:<secret_key>@chatbotcosmos.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb`. This is my new connection string after I recreated my database which I have copied exactly from Azure.

Comment: Sure its not getting the connection string from a different source? like appsettings.development.json when you debug it locally? Since the above one says `botframeworkcosmos.documents.azure.com` and yours `chatbotcosmos.documents.azure.com`

Comment: @Tseng Yes, I have a new connection string now after I deleted and recreated the database. Also, the config is correct which I have verified in debugging.

Comment: Do you have some special characters in your password? such as `/`, `:` or `@`? You can't have special chars in there because its an url (or have to escape it maybe)

Comment: @Tseng No. The password is auto generated by Azure. Something like this- `12pVpf5Y5spByBjHJkok2D0PfvaQYaTzmDGhZDXO96S0eH6RnQRuPkss4MksNYQjU6mx6d4YSbG3iajuFSkCxQ==`. This was my old password which was working yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error message (`A timeout occured after 30000ms` with `Unspecified` also mentioned). It was because my company's firewall was blocking outbound connections on the Cosmos Mongo port, e.g. TCP 10255.

I tested this by temporarily running the code outside of our company's network and the error went away (I verified that when I re-ran it again inside out company's network it still failed).

Therefore adding network firewall rule to allow outbound connections to TCP port 10255 should fix it.

Comment: Thanks. I would not be able to check it now but may be later.

Answer (score -1):

### Check to be Consider:

1. Connection string from Azure COSMOS DB Environment
2. MongoDB Driver Version

   ```
    private string userName = "FILLME";
           private string host = "FILLME";            
           private string dbName = "Tasks";
           private string collectionName = "TasksList";

         private IMongoCollection<MyTask> GetTasksCollection()
         {
           MongoClientSettings settings = new MongoClientSettings();
           settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress(host, 10255);
           settings.UseSsl = true;
           settings.SslSettings = new SslSettings();
           settings.SslSettings.EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;

           MongoIdentity identity = new MongoInternalIdentity(dbName, userName);
           PasswordEvidence evidence = new PasswordEvidence(password);
           settings.Credential = new MongoCredential("SCRAM-SHA-1", identity, evidence);
           MongoClient client = new MongoClient(settings);
           var database = client.GetDatabase(dbName);
           var todoTaskCollection = database.GetCollection<MyTask>(collectionName);
           return todoTaskCollection;
       }

        public List<MyTask> GetAllTasks()
        {
          try
          {
           var collection = GetTasksCollection();
           return collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();
           }
           catch (MongoConnectionException ex)
           {
             return new List<MyTask>();
           }
         }
   ```