# SSL handshake failed in cosmosdb mongo api with python

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, pymongo, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi, ssl-handshake

I am trying to connect a database in azure cosmos that uses the Mongo DB API in Python. When I create the client, I get the `SSL handshake failed error` and I don't know how to solve it. I am aware that there is some thread that talks about this issue, and I have added to my code its recommendation, however I have not been able to make it work.

I have added the `tlsCAFile=certifi.where()` when creating the client, but I have not been able to solve it. I have seen people recommending `ssl_cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_NONE` or `tlsAllowInvalidCertificates=True`, but I don't want to mute the problem and lose security. Furthermore, even assuming the security loss I have not been able to make it work.

I am relying on this Azure Cosmos help page to create my client. I have already configured the environment variables.

[Link to azure tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/how-to-python-get-started?tabs=venv-windows%2Cazure-portal%2Cdotenv#code-try-3)

This is my code summarized:

```
import getpass
import certifi
import pymongo
import os
import sys
import pymongo
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from random import randint

#[...]

def main():
    """Connect to the API for MongoDB, create DB and collection, perform
    CRUD operations
    """
    # Variable for resource group name
    load_dotenv()
    CONNECTION_STRING = os.environ.get("COSMOS_CONNECTION_STRING")
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(CONNECTION_STRING,tls=True,tlsCAFile=certifi.where())

    for prop, value in vars(client.options).items():
        print("Property: {}: Value: {} ".format(prop, value))

    try:
        client.server_info()  # validate connection string
    except pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError:
        raise TimeoutError(
            "Invalid API for MongoDB connection string \
                or timed out when attempting to connect"
        )

    collection = create_database_unsharded_collection(client)
    document_id = insert_sample_document(collection)

    read_document(collection, document_id)
    update_document(collection, document_id)
    delete_document(collection, document_id)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Any help is welcome, thank you very much in advance. I have also this question in [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1347090/ssl-handshake-failed-in-cosmosdb-mongo-api-with-py)

**EDIT:** I am working on a company's network, and I have read that it might cause problems. Could this be related to my issue?

I have `python (3.8.5)`, `python-dotenv (1.0.0)`, `certifi (2020.6.20)`, `pymongo (4.4.1)`, `dnspython (2.4.2)`. `MongoDB server version 4.2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to solve the problem. If you work with a company network, for security reasons they have some ports closed. In my case, port 10255 was closed for security reasons and the client was well configured.

[Link that helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53002562/unable-to-connect-to-mongo-db-with-azure-cosmos-db)