# Connection times out after upgrading MongoDB.Driver from 2.7.0 to 2.7.1

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, .net-core

I am using a MongoDB v3.6.2 instance on Docker in my local dev environment. Upgrading the `MongoDB.Driver` NuGet package from 2.7.0 to 2.7.1 makes the following code throw an exception.

```
string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost:27017/foo";
var database = new MongoClient(connectionString).GetDatabase("foo");
var collections = database.ListCollectionNamesAsync().Result.ToListAsync().Result;
```

I expect the list of collection as always, but the following exception is thrown instead.

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/localhost:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/localhost:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Socket.IOControl handles Windows-specific control codes and is not supported on this platform.
at System.Net.Sockets.SocketPal.WindowsIoctl(SafeCloseSocket handle, Int32 ioControlCode, Byte[] optionInValue, Byte[] optionOutValue, Int32& optionLength)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.IOControl(Int32 ioControlCode, Byte[] optionInValue, Byte[] optionOutValue)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.IOControl(IOControlCode ioControlCode, Byte[] optionInValue, Byte[] optionOutValue)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.CreateSocket(EndPoint endPoint)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.CreateStreamAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)" }] }.) ---> System.TimeoutException: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "Automatic", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/localhost:27017" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/localhost:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Socket.IOControl handles Windows-specific control codes and is not supported on this platform.
at System.Net.Sockets.SocketPal.WindowsIoctl(SafeCloseSocket handle, Int32 ioControlCode, Byte[] optionInValue, Byte[] optionOutValue, Int32& optionLength)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.IOControl(Int32 ioControlCode, Byte[] optionInValue, Byte[] optionOutValue)
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.IOControl(IOControlCode ioControlCode, Byte[] optionInValue, Byte[] optionOutValue)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.CreateSocket(EndPoint endPoint)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.CreateStreamAsync(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)" }] }.
at at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description)
at at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedHelper.HandleCompletedTask(Task completedTask)
at at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedAsync(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description, Task descriptionChangedTask, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServerAsync(IServerSelector selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupportedAfterSeverSelctionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupportedAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.StartImplicitSessionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at at MongoDB.Driver.MongoDatabaseImpl.UsingImplicitSessionAsync[TResult](Func`2 funcAsync, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

This was running on an Ubuntu 18.06 x64 machine with .NET SDK v2.1.403.

Comment: Also have this problem on mac os, .net sdk 2.1.302:(
on 2.7.0 everything works fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314245/a-timeout-occured-after-30000ms-selecting-a-server-using-compositeserverselector)

Comment: @dnickless not a duplicate. This was a bug and now is fixed in a recent release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem. They have just published 2.7.2. And it resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't an answer, but I lack the reputation points to comment.  I am also having this same problem. This morning I updated my driver to 2.7.1.  I don't see the problem in Windows, but I do see the problem when running my application in a linux docker container.

Update: 2.7.2 was published, and it fixed the problem for me.