# Docker Toolbox MongoDB C# TimeoutException

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core-webapi, docker-toolbox

I am new to docker and mongoDB, am using docker toolbox on widows 10 home machine.while I tried to follow a tutorial on medium on docker, .net core and mongodb am getting the following timeout error

> A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using
>   CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors =
>   MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector,
>   LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000
>   } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode
>   : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers :
>   [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:27017" }",
>   EndPoint: "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:27017", State: "Disconnected", Type:
>   "Unknown", HeartbeatException:
>   "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while
>   opening a connection to the server. --->
>   System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException: A
>   connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
>   respond after a period of time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to respond xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:27017
>   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<>c.b__271_0(IAsyncResult
>   iar)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.ConnectAsync(Socket
>   socket, EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.CreateStreamAsync(EndPoint
>   endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelperAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.HeartbeatAsync(CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken)" }] }.

**Configuration Class**

```
namespace TodoApp.Common.Config
{
 public class MongoDbConfig
 {
    public string Database { get; set; }

    public string Host { get; set; }

    public int Port { get; set; }

    public string User { get; set; }

    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string ConnectionString
    {
        get
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(User) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Password))
            {
                return $@"mongodb://{Host}:{Port}";
            }
            return $@"mongodb://{User}:{Password}@{Host}:{Port}/{Database}?connect=replicaSet";
        }
      }
     }
    }
```

**Context class**

```
namespace TodoApp.Common.Models
{
 public class TodoContext : ITodoContext
 {
    private readonly IMongoDatabase _db;

    public TodoContext(IOptions<MongoDbConfig> config)
    {
        var client = new MongoClient(config.Value.ConnectionString);
        _db = client.GetDatabase(config.Value.Database);
    }

    public IMongoCollection<Todo> Todos => _db.GetCollection<Todo>("Todos");
  }
 }
```

appsettings

```
"MongoDB": {
 "Database": "TodoDB",
 "Host": "xxx.xxx.xx.xxx",
 "Port": "27017",
 "User": "root",
 "Password": "example"
},
```

docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '3.1'
     services:
      mongo:
        image: mongo
        restart: always
        environment:
         MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
         MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: example
        ports:
         - 27017:27017
       mongo-express:
        image: mongo-express
        restart: always
        ports:
         - 8081:8081
        environment:
         ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
         ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
        depends_on:
         - mongo
```

Medium link : [this](https://medium.com/@kristaps.strals/docker-mongodb-net-core-a-good-time-e21f1acb4b7b)

Comment: Did you already double-check the username (case sensitive) and the fact that your docker ports are correctly mapped? Docker port 27017 needs to be mapped to your container's published port.

Comment: yes username is correct

Comment: What about ports? Also, see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314245/a-timeout-occured-after-30000ms-selecting-a-server-using-compositeserverselector

Comment: Tried still not working

Comment: Can you connect to your MongoDb cluster using mongo shell or Robomango (Robo 3T)? What I am getting at is you need to check the ports. I see you added docker-compose. Thanks

Comment: Yes you are right it's not reachable with the port that I had given, how can I the port

Comment: Am able to map the port. But now am facing with MongoDB.Driver.MongoAuthenticationException: Unable to authenticate using sasl protocol mechanism SCRAM-SHA-1. ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException: Command saslStart failed: Authentication failed..

Comment: Am able to solve the issue with correcting the ID and modifying the connection string by removing the  /{Database}?connect=replicaSet portion