# Mongo db connection issues

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core, mongodb-.net-driver

I am using c# .net core to connect to mongo db.The mongo db uses ssl and has a certificate. The certificate is placed in the current directory. The driver version is 2.10.4

```cs
string filePath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\somename.pfx";
//  var cert = new X509Certificate2(filePath);

var cert = new X509Certificate2(filePath, "password");

var settings = new MongoClientSettings
{
    SslSettings = new SslSettings
    {
        ClientCertificates = new[] { cert },
    },
    UseSsl = true
};
settings = MongoClientSettings.FromConnectionString(ApplicationConstants.MongoDBConnectionStr);

var client = new MongoClient(settings);
var db = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName);
var log = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("name");

var dataList = collection.Find(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Empty).ToList();
```

however it throws an exception at the line above

> A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server. ---> MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while receiving a message from the server. ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.

Comment: Hope this helps you [Mongo Timeout error CompositeServerSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314245/a-timeout-occured-after-30000ms-selecting-a-server-using-compositeserverselector)

Comment: No tried this one. didnt help.

Comment: I solved it finally using this link https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1227164/Using-Encryption-and-Authentication-to-Secure-Mong