# System.TimeoutException: 'A timeout occurred after 30000ms' Issue

Tags: c#, mongodb, timeout

When I run the section of my project in C# nothing happens for about 30 seconds and it sends that error message in the title above, I am currently using .NET 5 Framework, the latest mongo drivers and my own Mongo Host (I tried Mongo atlas and it didnt work either). I have no clue as to why this doesnt work and was wondering if anyone knew why.

```cs
MongoClientSettings settings = new MongoClientSettings();
settings.ConnectTimeout = new TimeSpan(1000);
settings.WaitQueueTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0);
settings.MinConnectionPoolSize = 1;
settings.MaxConnectionPoolSize = 25;
settings.Server = new MongoServerAddress("139.99.197.10");

Console.WriteLine(" connected");

MongoClient client = new MongoClient(settings);
database = client.GetDatabase(name);
```

```cs
public static bool DoesUserExist(String paramLicense)
{
    List<Profile> records = GetMongo().Load<Profile>("Users");
    bool correctCredentials = false;

    foreach (var record in records)
    {
        if (record.licenseKey.Equals(paramLicense, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            correctCredentials = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (correctCredentials) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: The error message is rather clear to me. There's a timeout in an operation. Which line has the problem?

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314245/a-timeout-occured-after-30000ms-selecting-a-server-using-compositeserverselector . It might help.

Comment: This sounds like a connection timeout - are you certain about your IP address? Maybe you need to specify a port also? Don't you need to specify username/password for that database connection?

Comment: @HansKeﬆing by default MonogDB does not use authentication - however it should be the very first option you enable.

Comment: @PMF List<Profile> records = GetMongo().Load<Profile>("Users") thats the issue, when mongo is called

Comment: Apparently, the database is unresponsive. Try with some tutorial code or check other answers on the same problem.