# Why do I always get [Http 500 Timed out] when trying to fetch data from Mongo?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, azure

So I've been on this for the past 2 days now and I just can't wrap my head around it:
I've created a database on mongodb aswell as a `Web Api` using the `Asp.Net` visual studio template.
The Api works fast locally and gives me the correct responses, but when deployed to azure I always get

```
System.TimeoutException: A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector
```

[I've made a pastebin which shows the whole error](https://pastebin.com/MqXQZJte)

So far I've tried:

```cs
return "Test string"
```

which works but as soon as I try to bring mongo into this it times out. Even if I'm just trying to name the database.

```cs
return _mongoclient.GetDatabase("MyDatabase").ToString()
```

Comment: you should provide the whole error message

Comment: The whole error message is 6k characters long.

Comment: what you provided has no meaning since it's just a "header"

Comment: you should post it in the description, so anyone can easy search it

Answer (score -1):

Add `"?connect=replicaSet"` to the end of your connection string if connecting to MongoLab.

```
new MongoClient("mongodb://username:password@ds011111.mongolab.com:11111/db-name?connect=replicaSet")
```

Basically the default is to connect to a replica set member. But MongoLab's Single-Node settings are actually a single node replica set and this causes us to not trust it. Appending `?connect=replicaSet` to your connection string will force the driver to move into replica set mode and all will work.

As you can see in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/43484598/19493343

Comment: I'm not connecting to Mongo lab. Just a normal cluster database.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).