# .net mongodb version 2.2 timeout exception

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have used mongoDb with .net
I have loaded mongodbdriver core and **BSon** from visual studio add-in manager for mongodb **.net core version 2.2**
* Now when i try to create a database and added some collection into it. 
It has giving me an error like below:

```
public async void insert(FilePath file)
{
    try
    {
        IMongoCollection<FilePath> collection = _db.GetCollection<FilePath>("FilePath");
        await collection.InsertOneAsync(file);
    }
    catch { };
}
```

Exception:

> A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using
>   CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = WritableServerSelector,
>   LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000
>   } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode
>   : "Automatic", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{
>   ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/localhost:27017"
>   }", EndPoint:

Comment: First, you need to replace `async void` to `async Task`. and call `insert` with `await`.

Comment: i tryed all. i think there is some bugs in this version 2.2 after some googling i found the answer in below. thank you

Comment: here the problem is not its async or Task. I Ask you open and clearly about connection timeout. please add comment if you have this type solution...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB C# 2.0 TimeoutException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832622/mongodb-c-sharp-2-0-timeoutexception)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First check the mongo server is running or not.**

Possibly you haven't started the Mongo server.

Open a shell and type

```
mongod
```

On the file system, you can start it from `$MONGO_INSTALL_PATH/bin/mongod`.

Don't close the shell and then try to run your code again.

More info:

- [Manage the mongod process](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/)

**OR**

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
```

But worked out when changed "locahost" to "127.0.0.1"

```
MongoClient mongo = new MongoClient("127.0.0.1", 27017);
```

Comment: I think you missed `L` in `localhost`