# MongoDB C# 2.0 TimeoutException during using findAll()

Tags: c#, mongodb

I HAVE THIS PROBLEM:

> A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using
>   CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = WritableServerSelector,
>   LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000
>   } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", Type :
>   "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId
>   : 1, EndPoint : "172.16.1.24:27017" }", EndPoint: "172.16.1.24:27017",
>   State: "Disconnected", Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException:
>   "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while
>   opening a connection to the server. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed
>   because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed because connected host has
>   failed to respond 172.16.1.24:27017    at
>   System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult
>   iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean
>   requiresSynchronization)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.d__4.MoveNext()
>   in
>   D:\jenkins\workspace\mongo-csharp-driver-2.0.x-build\src\MongoDB.Driver.Core\Core\Connections\TcpStreamFactory.cs:line
>   126
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.d__3.MoveNext()
>   in
>   D:\jenkins\workspace\mongo-csharp-driver-2.0.x-build\src\MongoDB.Driver.Core\Core\Connections\TcpStreamFactory.cs:line
>   55
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__32.MoveNext()
>   in
>   D:\jenkins\workspace\mongo-csharp-driver-2.0.x-build\src\MongoDB.Driver.Core\Core\Connections\BinaryConnection.cs:line
>   201    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.d__32.MoveNext()
>   in
>   D:\jenkins\workspace\mongo-csharp-driver-2.0.x-build\src\MongoDB.Driver.Core\Core\Connections\BinaryConnection.cs:line
>   225
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
>   at
>   MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ClusterableServer.d__34.MoveNext()
>   in
>   D:\jenkins\workspace\mongo-csharp-driver-2.0.x-build\src\MongoDB.Driver.Core\Core\Servers\ClusterableServer.cs:line
>   245" }] }.

```
        var conString = "mongodb://172.16.1.24:27017";
        var client = new MongoClient(conString);
        var server = client.GetServer();
        var database = server.GetDatabase("knjigoMata");
        var collection = database.GetCollection<ModelKorisici >("kljenti");

        //var entity = collection.FindAll();

        BindingList<ModelKorisici > doclist = new BindingList<ModelKorisici >();

        foreach (var deger in collection.FindAll())
        {
            doclist.Add(deger);
        }
        return doclist;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB C# 2.0 TimeoutException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832622/mongodb-c-sharp-2-0-timeoutexception)