# A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server while accessing MongoDB in Azure using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, azure, timeout

The .Net console app is in 4.6.1 framework, using MongoDB.Driver 2.8.0. I referred many posts in SO, but I still get the timeout error. Below are the some of the posts I referred

[A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31314245/a-timeout-occured-after-30000ms-selecting-a-server-using-compositeserverselector)
[System.TimeoutException: A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859755/system-timeoutexception-a-timeout-occured-after-30000ms-selecting-a-server-usin/51281357#51281357)
[MongoDB C# 2.0 TimeoutException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29832622/mongodb-c-sharp-2-0-timeoutexception)

Below is the code I have used to access the documents from the collection.

```
using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Driver;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string connectionString =
            @"mongodb://mongoaccnt:ADASDXZWADAS2VgsqTYcTS4gtADmB1zQ==@mongocnt.documents.azure.com:10255/?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb";

        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.FromUrl(
          new MongoUrl(connectionString)
        );

        settings.SslSettings = new SslSettings() { EnabledSslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12 };

        var mongoClient = new MongoClient(settings);
        string dbName = "app-db";
        string collectionName = "test";
        var database = mongoClient.GetDatabase(dbName);


        var todoTaskCollection = database.GetCollection<test>(collectionName);

        var filter = Builders<test>.Filter.Eq("name", "second");

        var results = todoTaskCollection.Find(filter).ToList();

        Console.WriteLine(results);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}

public class test
{
    public string name { get; set; }        
}
```

Below is the data showing in Azure cloud portal

```
db.test.find()
Operation consumed 2.31 RUs
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5ca4949fd59b290e00e35eda"), "id" : 1, "name" : "first" }
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5caafe968f678e0f504c6e64"),
    "id" : 2,
    "name" : "second"
}
```

Below is the detailed error

System.TimeoutException
  HResult=0x80131505
  Message=A timeout occured after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 } }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", ConnectionMode : "ReplicaSet", Type : "ReplicaSet", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1,

Comment: A database command defaults to 30 seconds timeout.  It can be made longer.  See : http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/reference/connecting/connection-settings/

Comment: @jdweng I added settings.ConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5); to the code, the issue persists.

Comment: How long does it take before the timeout occurs? If it is still 30 seconds then you are not finding the Server.  If it is failing after 5 minutes then it is the query that is taking a long time.  The error message I think is saying it can't find the server.  So either the server is not running (or not listening on port 10255), or there is no route (ethernet) to the server.  I would start by using cmd.exe and trying to ping server >Ping mongocnt.documents.azure.com

Comment: I fixed this error by correcting my port in my connection string. It wasnt matching what my local MongoDB was configured to.

Comment: It's been long since i posted this. It seems the issue was actually MongoDB port was blocked by the organization. Just got to know about it.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding "?connect=replicaSet" after your connection string :

This JIRA ticket has the details: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-1160

Effectively, They've made a distinction between connecting to a standalone server and connecting directly to a replica set member, where the latter is relatively uncommon. Unfortunately, MongoLab's Single-Node settings are actually a single node replica set and this causes us to not trust it. You can fix this by appending ?connect=replicaSet to your connection string. It will force the driver to move into replica set mode and all will work.

you can find more details on : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-csharp/O460OHiFjZs

Hope it helps.

Comment: I just went with CosmosDB, not sure why Mongo din't work.

Answer (score 1):

It's clear that you didn't add the database name inside the connection code.

Here's the template of the connection string

```
`var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://<dbuser>:<dbuserpassword>@<mongoaddress>/<dbname>?connect=replicaSet&ssl=true&replicaSet=<replicaset>&authSource=<authsource>");
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");`
```

You need to fill the following

- dbuser: user name of the user
- dbuserpassword: password of the database user
- dbname: name of the database
- mongoaddress: address of the mongodb shard
- replicaset: name of the replica set
- authsource: Authentication source