# c# How to extend time of mongo db transaction lifetime

Tags: c#, mongodb, transactions, mongodb-.net-driver

How to change [transactionLifetimeLimitSeconds](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/#param.transactionLifetimeLimitSeconds) in my cloud replica set.
Firstly i was creating new session:

```
var client = new MongoClient(new MongoUrl(_connectionString));           
var session= client.StartSession();
```

Next

```
session.StartTransaction();
/* Code that takes longer than 1 minute*/
session.CommitTransaction();
```

When the code between start and commit transaction ends im getting Error like

> Exception thrown: 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException' in MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll ("Command insert failed: Transaction 1 has been aborted..") Exception thrown: 'MongoDB.Driver.MongoCommandException' in MongoDB.Driver.Core.dll

If the code take less than 1 minute everything is ok.

Comment: The default timeout is 30 seconds with a connection.  The timeout is in the Command.

Comment: What do u mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# MongoDB Driver Ignores timeout options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825107/c-sharp-mongodb-driver-ignores-timeout-options)

Answer (score 2):

You can call this command `db.adminCommand( { setParameter: 1, transactionLifetimeLimitSeconds: 30 } )` like:

```
var adminDb = client.GetDatabase("admin");
adminDb.RunCommand<BsonDocument>("{ setParameter: 1, transactionLifetimeLimitSeconds: 30 }");
```

Also, check this transaction option: http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.11/apidocs/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_TransactionOptions_MaxCommitTime.htm, I believe it should help (but I didn't use it personally).

Comment: i was trying MaxCommitTime option but i think it just extend a commit time not whole transaction. I'll will try the second option to get access to admin database but im not sure i have insufficient permissions for that

Comment: @Wojna that wouldn't work. `MaxCommitTime` does not affect the time a transaction can remain open.